# How to extract information from column y after selecting specific rows in column x

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, multiple-columns

I am analyzing some data with several columns. Among them: 'id number', 'reaction times', 'error coding' (was an error made (x = 2) or not (x = 1)). Within this last column, I extracted all cells that follow a specific error pattern, i.e. 1-1-2-1. I used the function `strfind` in order to do that. 
Now i have a list of all row numbers that make part of this pattern, each pattern consisting of 4 rows. I just don't have a clue how to extract the corresponding rows from the column that contains the reaction times. without them, the pattern is useless. Any help with that?

Here is how I found my pattern inside the data.

```
errCode <- as.character(1121) # defining pattern
inrows <- strfind(paste(as.character(dat2$corrCodeFB), collapse = ""), errCode, overlap = FALSE) # searching for pattern inside error coding column  
rows <- unlist(lapply(inrows, "+", 0:3)) # extending pattern by adding the following 3 positions to 1st position
```

This produces a list of all row numbers, but how do I get the reaction times?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? Preferably, a bunch of rows that also include at least one occurrence of the pattern you're looking for. It can be either a real sample of your data, or some fake data just to help us understand your question. It is best to provide the sample using the output from a `dput(data[range])` call.

Comment: Also, are you simply looking for `dat[rows,]`?